# How to compile in -std=c99 in Geany

Tags: c, geany

I am coding up some .c files using Geany, and I am interested in compiling using the c99 standard.

I see that I can set build commands and I assume this is where I need to be, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct. Here are commands that I've tried in the Compile tab, but none seem to work;

```
gcc -std=c99  -Wall -c "%f"
gcc -Wall -c -std=c99 "%f"
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c "%f"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "none seem to work?" `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -c file.c` works fine for me.

Comment: Well part of my code, I have a declaration inside of the for loop, which seems to only work if you compile in the c99 standard. Using your build command, I still receive the error:        note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code

Comment: What about just fixing that darn for loop? :)

Comment: Yeah, putting the declaration outside of the for loop would solve this particular issue, but my professor has instructed us to always compile in the c99 standard so I'll eventually need to figure this out.

Comment: What were the arguments of Your professor for You to do so? and which GCC version are You using for that? Maybe You could provide minimal code example? The problem might be somewhere else...

Comment: @Kamiccolo: Declarations in `for` loops, like `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` are a new feature in C99; gcc rejects it unless you specify `-std=c99` or something similar. Any of the three commands in the question should work (the order of the options doesn't matter) -- *assuming* that `"%f"` expands to the name of the source file being compiled. I've never used Geany, so I don't know what syntax it expects.

Comment: Yes, %f will be replaces with the current opened file so it should work. If not, we need more details, what's not working -- kind of an error message or something.

Comment: If you go to Build > Set Build Commands, then add -std=c99 to Build and Compile lines, it should work fine.